# How to fix the "template0clear" error where creating or restoring database in odoo 15?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I am trying to restore one of my databases on odoo 15 but all of my attempts has failed throwing the following error `template database "template0clear" does not exist`.

First I thought maybe the template0 database is missing but I was wrong. I don't really know of a template database in postgresql named `template0clear`. Even if I do try to create a new one it fails with the same error any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is your server setup? Which postgresql version do you use?

Comment: You didn't describe how you tried to restore. This question belongs to DBA Stackexchange.

Comment: I tried to restore it through a backup zip file as usual. And when it comes to the version of postgresql, I am using 15